# node js with code igniter

Tags: node.js, codeigniter-2

I want to update the web page without refresh in my code igniter project.I am going to do it using node js.I installed node js.
I can run the js function through the terminal after run the node command.how I can use node js for update the code igniter web page?

thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12213067/codeigniter-node-js-integration-with-now-js-how-to-access-view-files
this may help you

Comment: This question is unclear. It is also old - so I'm not sure you're talking about updating a web-page's HTML content in the browser, while the user is navigating, or if you are talking about changing the actual view (in this case, a `.php` file that will be rendered by CodeIgniter). If its the last one, it honestly doesn't make a lot of sense. If its the first one, today there are established JS libraries which are prepared to seamlessly update the front end of any given webpages. Have a look at  [Vue](https://vuejs.org/), [React](https://en.reactjs.org/)